# minitest routing test htpp:200 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

i use minitest for test framework.

```
**routes.rb file**
Cultiva::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

  match "sign-up" => "identities#new", :as => :signup, method: :get
  match "sign-up" => redirect("auth/identity/register"), :as => :signup, method: :post
  match "sign-off" => "session#destroy", :as => :signoff
  resources :identities
```

route file is like above. i set sign-up page routes for get and post processes like above. when it posts, it redirect to "auth/identity/register" page. i set the post address of page as "auth/identity/register". i rote below test:

```
     it "must route to auth/identity/register when method is post" do
          post(signup_path).must_equal "/auth/identity/register"
      end


when i run this test, it gives error:

test_0002_must route to auth/identity/register when method is post(Route Integration Test::signup_path) [/home/developer/Projects/Bilsa/cultiva/test/routes/route_test.rb:13]:
Expected: "/auth/identity/register"
  Actual: 200
```